# sharepoint list name issue

Tags: windows-server-2008, sharepoint-2007

I am using SharePoint Server 2007 Enterprise with Windows Server 2008 Enterprise, and I am using publishing portal template. I heard for SharePoint list/list column, it has an internal name which could be used for programming (as identifier for list/list column), and also has a display name (which is showed for end user for list name or list column name).

How to find and set such internal name and display name for list/list column?

thanks in advance,
George

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are asking how to find the list GUID (Globally Unique Identifier), navigate to the list and choose Settings --> List Settings.  You'll get a URL that looks something like:

http://yourportal/_layouts/listedit.aspx?List=%7B16FF7A0D%2D0E12%2D47F7%2DB03E%2D59E59925FBBA%7D

That long string of characters at the end is your GUID, although it is URL encoded, so change:

the %7B to a {
all %2D to hyphens
the %7D to a }

Giving you a list GUID of: {16FF7A0D-0E12-47F7-B03E-59E59925FBBA}

(or easier, just use the URL encoding converter here: http://www.blooberry.com/indexdot/html/topics/urlencoding.htm)

Comment: Sorry, I do not mean GUID. I mean InternalName and Name of a field. Any ideas how to find InternalName and name of a column?

SPField f = //some field
f.InternalName;
f.Title;

Comment: Cool, question answered!